# Multiple jar file introspection

Tags: eclipse, shell, cygwin, weblogic

How do write a command on bash shell that can search a number of jar files in a directory for a specified class or string path. Eg

I want to search all *workshop*.jar searching for this string path:

```
com/bea/workshop/common/util/fileio/ManifestUtil
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
find . -name *.jar -exec bash -c "echo {} && jar tvf {} | grep ServiceMBean " \;
```

Good luck,
-M

Answer (score 0):

Find jars with containing pattern (class or file) create the following script **findjars** from the root directory of a search tree

```
#!/bin/bash
JAR=$JAVA_HOME/bin/jar
if [ $# -ne 1 ];
then
    echo "Usage: $0 pattern"
    exit 1
fi
pattern=`echo $1 | sed -e 's/\./\//g'`
echo "Searching for: [$pattern]"

if [ ! -e $JAR ];
then
    echo "$JAR does not exist"
    exit 1
fi

for file in `find . -type f \( -name "*.jar" -o -name "*.zip" \) -print`; 
do 
    $JAR tvf $file 2>/dev/null | grep ${pattern} 2>/dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ];
    then
        echo $file
    fi
done
```

and use it as

```
findjars com/bea/workshop/common/util/fileio/ManifestUtil
```

Alternatively, to list all classes and files within all of the jar files within a directory or directory tree:

```
#!/bin/bash
JAR=$JAVA_HOME/bin/jar
if [ ! -e $JAR ];
then
    echo "$JAR does not exist"
    exit 1
fi

for file in `find . -type f \( -name "*.jar" -o -name "*.zip" \) -print`;
do
    echo $file
    $JAR tvf $file 2>/dev/null
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [JarScan](http://www.inetfeedback.com/jarscan/).

```
Usage: java -jar jarscan.jar [-help | /?]
                [-dir directory name]
                [-zip]
                [-showProgress]
                <-files | -class | -package>
                <search string 1> [search string 2]
                [search string n]
```